# Avoiding setting env.workspace and other paths/settings too often in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have some scripts that are constantly setting env.workspace of arcpy. Usually, I have a caller script(**script1.py**) that may call some other script (**script2.py)**. I've created a file **globals.py** with the paths that never change:

```
import arcpy.env as env

rootPath="S:/workspace/MSc_git/ArcGis/"
layersPath=rootPath+'Layers/'
# Set the workspace environment to local file geodatabase
env.workspace=rootPath+'estagio_db.gdb'
```

In script1.py I have something like this:

```
import arcpy
import globals as g
from arcpy import da
arcpy.AddMessage("Importing arcpy outside ArcMap took %s seconds." % (time.clock() - t_start))
from cProfile import run


def main():
  ....
```

And I need to use env.workspace and sometimes the layerspath inscript2.py
How can I do this (should I import gloabl.py as well?)? should I pass it by argument when calling a function from script2.py in script1.py or is there any other way to accomplish this?

I know we should avoid global vars, but in this case, and since I need to centralize its definition I don't know how to do it well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a global in this case is fine, as you are using arcpy and by setting `arcpy.workspace` you're setting a giant global in arcpy anyway (which is bad library design but I digress)

Personally I would be passing in the values you need into script2 functions as it will make your code cleaner as you are reducing the reliance on global vars.